# Put a UITableView into editing mode without moving the TextLabel?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I've got a UITableView that is sortable, but that's it. Right now, I have all the cells set to  UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone, but this still moves the TextLabel of the cell over to the right by 40 pixels. Is there anyway to get edit mode, and the sort icon at the right, without shifting the TextLabel over?

Comment: have you tried tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:?  It's not clear if that would help or not.

Comment: I just tried setting the indentationLevel of the cells to zero, but I think they were at zero to start, so it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is `- tableView: shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` in the delegate. Have that return `NO`.