# Grouped UITableView & edit-mode: strange behaviour

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

recently I implemented an grouped UITableView with editing, but the problem is: if the UITableView is in edit-mode, the content of the cells is moved to the right and this looks really unattractive.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sascha

Comment: That is not strange behavior at all. It's by design. With that said, what do you wish to accomplish then?

Comment: OK, I see. I don't want the cells to be moved to the right. Unfortunately I can't attach a screenshot (< 10 posts).

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611396/put-a-uitableview-into-editing-mode-without-moving-the-textlabel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;  
}
```